# Why dollar sign and brackets inside string do not work? Javascript/npm/react

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, brackets, dollar-sign

I am taking HTML/CSS/JS course. There is exercise to create web app with robofriends. There should be many robofriends photos, but I got return only the same. Could you please check if I am doing something wrong? Brackets inside string do not work: <img alt='robots' src={"https://robohash.org/${id}?200x200"} />

As is
[MyFriends](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4LvcC.png)

As should be
[RoboFriends](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BnpG6.png)

Code

```
    import React from 'react';



const Card = (props) => {
    const { email, name, id } = props;

    return (
        

        <div className="tc bg-light-green dib br3 pa3 ma2 grow bw2 shadow-5">
            <img alt='robots' src={"https://robohash.org/${id}?200x200"} />
            <div>
            <h2> {name} </h2>  
            <p>{email}</p>  
            </div>
        </div>
    );
}

export default Card;


    enter code here
```

Comment: use backticks(\`) instead of double quote(")

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use backticks like so:

```html
  <img alt='robots' src={`https://robohash.org/${id}?200x200`} />
```

Answer (score 1):

[Template literals](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals) are used with backticks, in your example you should replace the `src` in the `img` tag with the following:
`` src={`https://robohash.org/${id}?200x200`} ``.

Answer (score 0):

Double quotes don't support ${}.

Use:

```html
<img alt='robots' src={`https://robohash.org/${id}?200x200`} />
```

Or

```html
<img alt='robots' src={"https://robohash.org/" + id + "?200x200"} />
```